# Database for ethereum dapp development

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cassandra, blockchain, ethereum

I want to build a dapp with ethereum blockchain and apache cassandra / mongodb. Is it the correct way to build a blockchain?

My idea is use ethereum to create account and do all ERC-20 token and user credential stuff and cassandra / mongodb as the database for the dapp. I will use nodejs as server to communicate with each other. The reason why I'm trying to do this, is because ethereum blockchain is costly.

Comment: What you're asking is more opinion based. Technically speaking, there's nothing preventing you from using a hybrid solution with a blockchain and a more traditional backend persistence layer. Supporters would agree with you that it is costly and takes more time to execute methods, so a hybrid solution makes sense. Purists would say the whole point of using a blockchain is for decentralization and a hybrid solution goes against that.

Comment: I see, so i think is not a problem for me to use the nosql database (distributed) on my dapp, just need to take care of the security right ?

Besides that, do you familiar with the ethereum gas ? because i trying to pay the gas for the user in my dapp. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, paying for gas on behalf of your users pretty much requires your own backend. You need to unlock the account that will pay for gas and there are security issues with attempting to centralize that within the dApp itself, as you obviously don’t want your password on the client. I’m not aware of a solution that will let you do that securely.

Comment: But i have to help them refill the gas first right ? There is some transaction mining period need to wait before that can start execute my function right? Thanks

Comment: Gas isn't "refilled". Gas is just a measurement of how expensive operations are when executing contract code. Each operation has a fixed amount of gas consumed. You can change the amount of ether you're willing to pay for the gas consumed which will affect how quickly the transaction is mined.

cost = gas * gasPrice

See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0 for gas consumed for different operations.

You may want to seek out additional Ethereum tutorials.

Comment: would i be able to make a function on the smart contract when a person that used a dApp which require gas to execute the transaction, but instead of the user pay for gas, the owner of the smart contract ( i.e the operator/owner of the smart contract) pay for the gas instead?
user = the one which use the dApp to execute transaction
me = as the smart contract owner

Comment: No, this is not supported.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply :D